# controlling the height of the carousel size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am trying to make sure that my carousel size stay the same in terms of height.  I am using different images and i understand the image size are different but not sure how to control the height of the image.  I want my carousel height stay the same regardless of the image size so how can i control that?  here is the code i am using:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide"  data-ride="carousel" >
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <%--<img src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">--%>
          <img src="img/sleep1.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345" />
          <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Example headline.</h1>
              <p>this is test </p>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
       <%-- <img src="img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">--%>
          <img src="img/image5.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345"/>

      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <%--<img src="img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">--%>
          <img src="img/nature3.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="145" />
          <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Example headline.</h1>
              <p>this is test </p>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <%--<img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">--%>
          <img src="img/nature2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="245"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: On the class `item` set a height `height: 400px;` - Simple as that. Also you should include all relevant code (CSS).

Comment: thanks Ruddy, is this what you mean: <img src="img/image5.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height: 400px;/>  ?  i am not really following..

Comment: Im going to guess you have little experience with web development. You should go and look around as this sort of thing is very basic. `<img src="img/image5.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="400px"/>` is what you would want to do then.  If you wanted to set the image to that height.

Comment: i have tried that it did not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the class `.item` add some custom CSS that overrides Bootstraps core CSS like so:

```
 <style>
 .carousel-inner > .item > img,
 .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
     display: block;
     max-width: 100%;
     height: 400px !important;
 }
 </style>
```

This will make the carousel size 400px.

By default, the height is set to auto, but since we don't want that, we manually set a size and say that it's `!important` so the browser knows that this style is overruling the bootstrap css set prior.

I hope this helps and makes sense.

Comment: thanks Jason, that fixed the issue of height but now the width is smaller now and before the width was the same size as the carousel.  please help.  thanks

Comment: Hmm, try setting the width to a certain desired width as well. Or try setting it to auto.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by just adding this code into the  tag

```
<div id="Div1" class="carousel" runat="server" style="height:800px !important;">
```

its automatically increase the size and if you want add width too.
Thank you